# What does Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) actually mean?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Could you give me a detailed explanation on what the code above is doing step by step? I don't really understand how it works and how it links to me later being able to do this statement:

```
int i = input.nextInt()
```

Comment: Do you know what a `class` means in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @moffeltje I do know what class and objects mean in C++, though I haven't get to that part in Java.

Comment: Do you know what IO streams/readers/writers are? Do you know what is `System.in`?

Comment: @Pshemo It is an object that reads input from specifically the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it is input standard input stream which is meant to read data from user (by default from keyboard). Now Scanner is class which is meant to read data from streams (or even readers) in textual form. So its instance needs to know which stream it needs to read. We pass this information via constructor just like in your case, since we want Scanner to read from standard input stream we are using `new Scanner(System.in);`. Then we store created instance in `input` reference. This lets us use methods like` nextInt()` `nextLine()` which are not available for `InputStream`.

Comment: @Pshemo Got it now. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: BTW, as mentioned earlier Scanner can be used to read data as text from any InputStream or Reader. So it can also read from file if you pass instance of FileInputStream or FileReader, or any source which can be wrapped by any InputStream/Reader.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, let's elaborate with some simplified explanation about the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

It is a standard Oracle class which you can use by calling the `import java.util.Scanner`.

So let's make a basic example of the class:

```
class Scanner {
   InputStream source;

   Scanner(InputStream src) {
       this.source = src;
   }

   int nextInt() {
       int nextInteger;
       //Scans the next token of the input as an int from the source.
       return nextInteger;
   }
}
```

Now when you call `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` you make a new object of the `Scanner` class (so you make a new "Scanner") and you store it in the variable `input`. At the same time you are calling the (so called) [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)) of the class, with the parameter `System.in`. That means it is going to read from the standard input stream of the program.

Now when you are calling `input.nextInt();` you execute the method from the object you just created (also [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())). But as we see, this method returns a integer, so if we want to use that integer, we have to assign the call to a variable like you do:

```
int i = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 7):

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` creates a *new* `Scanner` instance which points to the *input stream* passed as argument. In your case the steam is *Standard input stream*.

So, once your scanner instance is pointing to it, you can *scan* the stream and get `integers`, `strings` and do other stuff .

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Creates a new object of type `Scanner` from the standard input of the program (in this case probably the console)
and

```
int i = input.nextInt()
```

uses the `nextInt` Method of that object, which allows you to enter some text and it will be parsed into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Above statement creates an object of `Scanner` class which is defined in `java.util.scanner` package. `Scanner` class allows user to take input from console.

`System.in` is passed as a parameter in `Scanner` class. It tells the java compiler that system input will be provided through console(keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
it creates a new Scanner instance which points to the input stream passed as argument. So here the steam is Standard input stream.

So, once your scanner instance is pointing to it, you can scan the stream and store the value into integers, strings and do other things