# I have to print the array , but for each loop is not working

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeacherCoins {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    int k;

    System.out.print("Enter total number of coins :");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    k =sc.nextInt();

    int [] arr= new int[k-1];
    System.out.print("Enter array :");

    for(int i=0;i<=(k-1);i++) 
    {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        arr[i] =sc1.nextInt();

    }

    for(int element :arr)
    {
    System.out.println("Print array");
    System.out.println(element);

    }
}
```

I am giving output using Scanner class. But is not printing the array.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. Why are you declaring a `Scanner` object inside the for loop body? Why are you creating the array with `k - 1` elements?

Comment: As a small note, you don't need to construct a second scanner. You can keep using the previous scanner `sc`.

Comment: I have to give input to array , so i have created the scanner class. I have removed and tried by closing the scanner. Still it is not printing the array.

Comment: You're overflowing the array because it's one element smaller than it needs to be. So you get an exception that terminates your program. `int [] arr= new int[k];` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this code,
 1. You don't need to create a new `Scanner` object for each user input.
 2. You are declaring an array size of `k-1` and then asking user input `k` times.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k;
        System.out.print("Enter total number of coins :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        k = sc.nextInt();

        int[] arr = new int[k];  // To store k elements, you need k sized array
        System.out.print("Enter array :");
        for (int i = 0; i <= (k - 1); i++) {
            // Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in); / / Not required here
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println("Print array");
        for (int element : arr) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enter total number of coins :8
Enter array :1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at TeacherCoins.main(TeacherCoins.java:19)

Comment: This is the output with exception. how can i stop the scanner .I have user scanner.close also . it is continually asking , if i give the 9th number it ended up with exception due this , next code is not executing.

Comment: @Shafi It works fine for me. Also, the array ```size``` should be same as the ```number of array``` elements.

Comment: You are giving ```total number of coins :8``` but the array has 9 elements ```1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9```.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the Scanner again inside the loop. Another thing that you should do to be sure of your code, is to have this condition on the loop **if i < arr.length**. Lastly, I moved the "Print array" message outside the last for.

```
public class TeacherCoins {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int k;

        System.out.print("Enter total number of coins :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        k =sc.nextInt();

        int [] arr = new int[k];
        System.out.print("Enter array :");

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] =sc1.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Print array");
        for(int element :arr){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one problem in your code you are declaring the size of array as k-1 instead declare it for k elements.You just need to give each inputs in new line. For more refer this :[Scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612811/what-does-scanner-input-new-scannersystem-in-actually-mean/30613358).
And your for each loop is correct and working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TeacherCoins {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int k;
    System.out.print("Enter total number of coins :");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    k =sc.nextInt();
    int [] arr= new int[k];//it was giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    System.out.print("Enter array :");
    for(int i=0;i<=(k-1);i++)
    {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);//not required
        arr[i] =sc1.nextInt();//use arr[i] =sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(int element :arr)
    {
        System.out.println("Print array");
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

}
Above code will work. But you don't need new scanner objects for taking input, creating only single object will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeacherCoins {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int k;

        System.out.print("Enter total number of coins :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        k = sc.nextInt();

        int[] arr = new int[k];

        System.out.print("Enter array :");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }
        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Print array");

        for (int element : arr) {

            System.out.println(element);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; i < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                count++;

            }
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " " + count);

        }
    }
}
```