# Java Scanner and next() method -- what does it really mean, "next"?

Tags: java

Thanks to [the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612811/what-does-scanner-input-new-scannersystem-in-actually-mean), I get to understand

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = input.nextInt()
```

To understand more thoroughly, I read [the API document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612811/what-does-scanner-input-new-scannersystem-in-actually-mean) and it said:

> The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion
> methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that
> matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next
> token.

Can anyone interpret this sentence for me? Whenever I think of the "next()" method, I wonder why it is called next.

Comment: I think the answer is in the documentation that you quoted. "return[s] the **next** token"

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong My question was why it would skip the input that matches the delimiter pattern and then attempt to return the "next" token. Is it something I shouldn't care about?

Comment: That just means that the delimiter is not included in the return value.  The delimiter for `nextInt()` is a line separator, so what the documentation is saying is that it skips over the line separator and returns the next token (up to the next line separator).  If this weren't the case, the return value would always start with a line separator (and `nextInt()` would fail because line separators are not numbers).

Answer (score -1):

"Next" is build in function to use for input data, This is one in many way to input data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The `next()` function is designed to get inputs from users. You can use `nextInt()` if you want to get numbers as input.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).